# How to show a view in every screen at bottom

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I would like to add a bottom view in all view controllers which will show the progress of Audio or video play.[I need Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odgcR.png)

i did in the following

```
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!
let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: window.frame.origin.x, y: window.frame.origin.y, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height))
window.addSubview(v);
v.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
let v2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50))
v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
window.addSubview(v2)
```

But its not displaying in every screen.

Comment: Why don't you better create a custom UIViewController with the view already at the bottom and make all your others ViewController inherit from this?

Answer (score 3):

I have an approach for you.
Firstly you have to manage this in global way.

1. You need to create an Object of `AppDelegate`. And make a function in that class in which you can code
2. Then on loading your main view, you need to call that function so it will be visible as you want.

Comment: Could you please present some code examples? Or at least propose which method of AppDelegate you would implement? If your solution reacts only on loading main view how does it answer problem of displaying something on every screen?